# Set StorageQuota on existing site collection using CSOM and Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, csom, storage

Is there a way to set storage- and resource-quota on **existing** site collection using CSOM and Powershell?

- there is no `MaximumStorageLevel` property like at `SiteCreationInformation`
- using Powershell `Set-SPOSite` is not an option
- I can pull property bags for webs using `$ctx.Web.AllProperties`, but I didn't find a similar option for `$ctx.Site`
- I am aware of Auto Storage feature coming soon - it's also not an option

Any help or pointing in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would set-sposite not be an option if you are using powershell? Have you not installed the SPO cmdlets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why Set-SPOSite would not be an option if you are using PowerShell, install the components, you'd need to install the DLLs for the client side components anyway.

```
#The size in MB to set existing site collections
$newQuota = 10240
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
foreach($site in $sites){
    #If the site has a storage quota of zero, it is managed internally, skip over it
    if($site.StorageQuota -ne 0){
        Set-SPOSite -Identity $site -StorageQuota $newQuota
    }
}
```

Just last week I created these in our PowerShell module, again, there is no reason here that prevents you from using set-sposite to manage video channel quotas:

```
#region Office Video
function Get-SPOVideoChannels {
    <#
        .Synopsis
           Pulls back all the video channels in Office 365 Video
        .DESCRIPTION
           Pulls back all the video channels in Office 365 Video
        .EXAMPLE
           $videos = Get-SPOVideoChannels
            foreach($channel in $videos.GetEnumerator()){
                $channel
            }
        .OUTPUTS
           Returns a collection of channels
        .NOTES
           This operation takes a little time to complete, be patient
    #>  

    $channelInventory = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
    $SPOQueryUrl= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27contentclass:sts_site WebTemplate:POINTPUBLISHINGTOPIC%27&SelectProperties=%27Sitename%27&rowlimit=5000"

    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($SPOQueryUrl)
    $request.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
    $request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    $request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose"
    $request.Method = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]::Get

    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $readStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $requestStream
    $data = $readStream.ReadToEnd()

    $results = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
    $N4result = $results.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.Cells.results
    $Channels = @()
    foreach($r in $N4result){
        if($r.Key -eq "SiteName") {
            $Channels += $r.Value
        }           
    }

    foreach($chname in $Channels){
          $site = Get-SPOSite -Identity $chname -Detailed
          $channelInventory.Add($site.Title, [PSCustomObject] @{
            URL = $site.URL
            StorageGB = [System.Math]::Round(($site.StorageUsageCurrent/1024),2)
            QuotaGB = ($site.StorageQuota/1024)
            WarningGB = [System.Math]::Round(($site.StorageQuotaWarningLevel/1024),2)
            UsagePercentage = [System.Math]::Round(($site.StorageUsageCurrent/$site.StorageQuota)*100,0)
          })
    }
    return $channelInventory            
}
function Set-SPOChannelQuotas {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Updates site quota settings.
        .DESCRIPTION    
        Updates site quota settings.
        .PARAMETER Url
        The site collection Url
        .PARAMETER GBs
        The storage tier in GB.
        .EXAMPLE
        Updating a project space
        Set-SPOChannelQuotas -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/portals/communications" -GBs 5 
    #>  
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The channel URL",Position=0)][ValidateNotNull()]
            [string]$Url,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The storage tier in GBs",Position=1)][ValidateSet("1","5","10","15","20","25")]
            [string]$GBs
        )
    switch ($GBs){
                "5" {
                    $storage = 5120
                    $warn = 4608
                }
                "10" {
                    $storage = 10240
                    $warn = 9216
                }
                "15" {
                    $storage = 15360
                    $warn = 13824
                }
                "20" {
                    $storage = 20480
                    $warn = 18432
                }
                "25" {
                    $storage = 25600
                    $warn = 23040
                }
                default {
                    $storage = 1024
                    $warn = 922
                }
            }

    Set-SPOSite -Identity $Url -StorageQuotaWarningLevel $warn -StorageQuota $storage
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Set-SPOSite is not working for a) video channels b) sites stuck in updating c) few more situations. I have SharePoint Online Management Shell and can apply Set-SpoSite for most of the site collections. That's not the case here.

Comment: You can still use set-sposite to set video channel quotas, if it can be set through the UI, you can do it in PowerShell with set-spsite.

Comment: Let me repeat once again - Set-SPOSite is not an option. User Interface is not an option either, because the video channels do not show in the site collections list. Since apparently you are doing it this way, can you post a screen how you edit storage quota via UI for video channels that are not listed among the site collections in the SPO Admin Center?

Comment: How are channels not displayed in the site collection list? Every video channel I've created always shows

Comment: @grisha updated with more information. Hope this helps.